# How to get offsets for ElectraTokenizer

Tags: nlp, tokenize, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use **ELECTRA** model from **HuggingFace** library. However, I need to get the offsets for `ElectraTokenizer`, which can be done straightforward, according to [docs](https://huggingface.co/transformers/_modules/transformers/tokenization_electra.html#ElectraTokenizer). Does anyone know how can I get them? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your question including an [mcve] of your problem. In the current state, it is difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to get the offsets for ElectraTokenizer. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: The problem is that it is not clear what you mean by *offsets* based on the (unrelated) link that is included.